# What is the use case for HANDLER OPEN/READ/CLOSE?

Tags: mysql

Besides `INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT/DELETE` MySQL has something called [HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/handler.html). I've read that it can be considerable faster than normal `SELECTs` and I've tried it some in MySQL console and it seems fast.

However, the only information I found is at that single page from the reference manual and from what I can tell it isn't useful for anything but looking at data in the console.

So, does anyone have any Real Life[tm] experience using `HANDLERs` in MySQL?
Can I use it instead of `SELECT` inside a stored procedure?
Can I assign variables from any of the columns like `SELECT col INTO variable`?
Can I do joins or do I have do them *manually* from several `HANDLERs`?

Comment: Which backend do you use to connect to MySQL? Which language?

Comment: The C api does not have an entry for handlers, so it seems that there's no support about of the MySQL CLI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-function-overview.html

Comment: I use JDBC but if it's available inside functions and procedures that would also make it available everywhere...

Comment: `Can I use it instead of SELECT inside a stored procedure?` yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add my own answers here until I find better ones

> Can I use it instead of SELECT inside a stored procedure?

No. You get an `ERROR 1314 (0A000) at line 10: HANDLER is not allowed in stored procedures` when trying to compile the procedure.